# How do I enable the Compiler warnings(CMake), on qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, g++, qt-creator

So I used to have warnings while I was editing my c++ code in qt creator, but sadly, had to install it again for various problems.. Now while I'm editing the code it doesn't show me any warnings like I used to have,

for example:
[image: This is an example off Warnings i used to]

But now I only have the warnings when I run the file..

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TD06 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


# ask for all warnings and strict compliance with the standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -pedantic-errors")


add_executable(TD06 main.cpp polynomial.cpp polynomial.h)
```

I tried to search the problem by searching if someone had the same, or went to look on qt website but didn't find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be a little late, but you can turn them back on by going to Edit -> Preferences -> C++ -> Clangd and checking the first checkbox saying "Use clangd".